# Overview of Edward Kmetts packages for Haskell

Tags: haskell, category-theory

I remember at one point seeing an overview of Kmetts packages in some Haskell package, but I don't find it anymore.

It showed all of Kmetts packages (or at least a significant subset) and all the dependencies between them.

Can somebody direct me to where I can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀